# How to understand $\mathrm d x$ in the definite integral symbol?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

In the following integral formula, I have doubts about understanding the content of the red line. If we take out the underlined formula separately, how should we judge the integral variable and what is the integral range?[image]

Comment: Look at changing (substitution) variable in integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost every paper, especially in physics papers, when you encounter an integral with the expression $\mathrm d g(t)$, where $g$ is a differentiable function it simply means
$$\int_a^b f(t) \, \mathrm{d}g(t) = \int_a^b f(t)g'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.$$
Often times this notation is used to make integration by parts more practical or simpler.

In your case where you drew the red arrow $f(t)=R_n''(t)$ and $g(t)=(t-x)^2$, with $g'(t)=2(t-x).$

There is a way to make this entire idea more rigorous, which is the theory of [Riemann-Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) integrals.

Answer (score 2):

At that point in the calculation, the variable $x$ is considered a constant, so $t-x$ is a linear function in $x$.  Note that, for clarity, this should be written as $d\big((t-x)^2)$.  The author is simply skipping a step instead of using a more explicit substitution $u=(t-x)^2$.  Having said this, I don't quite follow the calculation.  Are you sure this is from a reliable source?  He seems to be applying integration by parts but the details seem a little obscure.

Comment: It comes from my mathematical analysis textbook. I think this step of transformation is extremely confusing, because I think if we take out the formula of the red line alone, we will not be able to determine what the integral variable is and what the integral interval is.

Comment: @ZehanLi, You could try to perform the calculation with an explicit substitution $u=(t-x)^2$ to see if it works out with the result claimed by the textbook.  If it doesn't, well, there are mistakes even in textbooks.